# Flask issue: if request.form["action"] == "Some Button": throwing up Syntax error in PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, syntax, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to have a simple form where a user can enter several things in a text box one at a time and, when ready, hit a button to run a function on the data they've entered.

Here's the whole page in flask_app.py

```
@app.route("/actors", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def actors():
    if "actors" not in session:
        session["actors"] = []
    if "characters" not in session:
        session["characters"] = []
    errors = ""
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            session["actors"].append(str(request.form["Actor"]))
            session.modified = True
            session["characters"].append(str(request.form["Character"]))
            session.modified = True

        if request.form["action"] == "Highlight Scripts":
            input_file = request.files["input_file"]
            actors = session["actors"]
            characters = session["characters"]
            for i in range(len(actors)):
                response = highlight(actors[i], characters[i])
                response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=result.pdf"
                return response
            
            session["actors"].clear()
            session.modified = True
            session["characters"].clear()
            session.modified = True
            return '''
                <html>
                    <body>
                        <p>{result}</p>
                        <p><a href="/actors">Click here to submit a new script</a>
                    </body>
                </html>
            '''.format(result=result)

    if len(session["actors"]) == 0:
        actors_so_far = ""
    else:
        actors_so_far = "<p>Actors so far:</p>"
        for a in session["actors"]:
            actors_so_far += "<p>{}</p>".format(a)

    return '''
        <html>
            <body>
                {actors_so_far}
                {errors}
                <p>Enter an actor:</p>
                <form method="post" action="/actors">
                    <p><input name="actor" /></p>
                    <p><input type="submit" name="action" value="Add another" /></p>
                    <p><input type="submit" name="action" value="Highlight Scripts" /></p>
                </form>
            </body>
        </html>
```

Where

```
if request.form["action"] == "Highlight Scripts":
```

gives a Syntax error.

Not sure how to proceed and appreciate any advice!

This is ripped/riffed from [this PythonAnywhere tutorial](https://blog.pythonanywhere.com/169/#sessions-to-the-rescue), where we use basically the exact same code to get a bunch of user-submitted #s

Comment: You have a try without any except.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @ewokx;

You do not have an `except` with `try`:

If you don't want to change your code you can do except:pass (though this is not recommended)

```
if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            session["actors"].append(str(request.form["Actor"]))
            session.modified = True
            session["characters"].append(str(request.form["Character"]))
            session.modified = True
        except:
            pass

        if request.form["action"] == "Highlight Scripts":
            input_file = request.files["input_file"]
            actors = session["actors"]
            characters = session["characters"]
            for i in range(len(actors)):
                response = highlight(actors[i], characters[i])
                response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=result.pdf"
                return response
```

Link to docs: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html